# Finding max and identify name's cell for another column

Tags: r, max

Hopefully someone can solve me the following problem.

Here I have a data about different birds and their maximum lengths:

```
a<-c("bird1","bird2","bird1","bird3","bird2","bird2")
b<-c(32,45,35,25,51,47)
c<-data.frame(animal=a,max=b)
  animal max
1  bird1  32
2  bird2  45
3  bird1  35
4  bird3  25
5  bird2  51
6  bird2  47
```

My purpose is to identify the name of the animal which has the maximum length. I know that using `max()`and `which.max()`is easy to identify the maximum length and the corresponding cell but how can I know the name of the animal?

Any valuable comment will be helpful for me!

Comment: Avoid the use of "c" to store variable, as it is built-in (and important) function. Try `with(c, animal[which.max(max)])`. But this will work only of you have no ties.

Comment: Ok, but if I do not use ties then I could no put the name of the birds, I should use numbers...

Comment: I don't see what you mean.

Comment: '> a<-c(bird1,bird2,bird1,bird3,bird2,bird2)
Error: object 'bird1' not found'

Comment: Yes, they should be string: "bird1" and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will provide the output of the bird with highest age

**Modification**

```
a<-c("bird1","bird2","bird1","bird3","bird2","bird2")
b<-c(32,45,35,25,51,47)
compined_birds<-data.frame(animal=a,max=b)
compined_birds$animal[which.max(compined_birds$max)]
```